# Google Data Flow - Apache Beam StreamingOptions.streaming not working

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have created an Apache Beam pipeline that works successfully when running on a Direct Pipeline. See issue below:-

[BigQuery writeTableRows Always writing to buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915242/bigquery-writetablerows-always-writing-to-buffer/49991603#49991603)

When the same code is pushed to Google DataFlow it changes to Streaming and won't batch.

```
                 rows.apply("Load", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                            .to(table)
                            .withSchema(schema)
                            //.withTimePartitioning(timePartitioning)
                            .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS)
                            .withTriggeringFrequency(triggeringFrequency)
                            .withNumFileShards(numFileShards)
                            .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

We have changed the Options for the Pipeline like so:-

```
   DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);          
            options.setProject(projectId);
            options.setTempLocation(tempLocation);
            options.setStreaming(false);
            options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
```

But the setStreaming here seems to be largely ignored.

What setting is required to use batching on Google Dataflow?

Comment: Curious about this as this looks all good. Which values are you setting for `triggeringFrequency` and `numFileShards`? How do you know that it is not batching? B/C the fact that the job is streaming doesn't mean that writing to BQ is streaming as well necessarily.

Comment: @Carlos -
triggeringFrequencyis set to 2 seconds
numFileShards is currently set to 1

We were keen to go with Batching as its cheaper.

Comment: I understand. I'd advise you to go with a higher `triggeringFrequency` as if you think about it, running a load job every 2 seconds will get you [rate limited](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) after half an hour or so for a whole day (max 1k jobs per day). Also, again, why do you know that you're not actually batching? B/C the fact that the job is streaming doesn't mean batch load jobs are not happening.

Comment: I don't know that its not batching.

What I know is that its set to "Streaming" true which runs 4 CPU's and hence higher cost.

I need "Streaming" set to false so I can reduce the cost.

Batching or not batching is not an issue as much as the cost incurred is.

Comment: Well... I think we're mixing things up here... The job and the BQ insertion methods are different things and may be in different modes (batch or streaming). I thought you wanted to have batch inserts, which I think you actually have, given your config. Regarding the job it is streaming probably because the input is unbounded (pubsub/kafka/generatesequence...). Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah. I've done a bunch of things to try and bound my unbounded input however nothing seems to work. :-(

Comment: Well... I guess that may not be possible. I mean, if your input is by nature unbounded (kafka, pubsub, ...) Then I don't think there's a way of making it bounded.

Comment: FYI @Carlos we gave up in the end and streamed it!